# ZSH Path Autocompletion Highlight

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, syntax-highlighting

In ZSH, when I'm trying to `cd` into a directory and use tab to get the list of directories, some of them have this very bright green highlight. I noticed that the background highlight is the same as that of directories in `ls`. I changed `LS_COLOR` hoping that would fix it, but the autocompletion highlight remains the same. I checked the zstyle completion keys/configs as well but didn't find any for directories there. Could someone help me fix this?

[image: 1]]

Thanks

EDIT: Here is a link to my `.zshrc` file: https://dpaste.org/V8oE

EDIT2: I was able to solve this by changing the theme on my terminal (Konsole). I don't think it was ZSH's problem.

Comment: We can't help since you didn't show your zsh configuration. Are you using a framework, and if so which one? Post your `.zshrc` and any applicable file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 
I'm using oh-my-zsh with the powerline plugins. I've updated the original post with a link to my `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

zsh's coloured completion is configured with the `list-colors` zstyle (see `info zsh list-colors` for details).

Your `~/.zshrc` or any other customisation file it calls may have something like:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

For that to be based on the contents of the `$LS_COLORS` variable (so you get the same colors in zsh completions as in GNU `ls --color` output).

`$LS_COLORS` is the variable used by GNU `ls`, and is generally set by a call to something like:

```
eval "$(dircolors --sh ~/.dircolors)"
```

(maybe earlier in your `~/.zshrc`, or in your `~/.zprofile`).

In

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

however, the `$LC_COLORS` is expanded and split on `:` **at the time `~/.zshrc` is interpreted**.

If you change `$LS_COLORS`, that `zstyle` command is not going to be run again automatically, and if you source your `~/.zshrc` again after modifying `$LS_COLORS`, it's possible the `dircolors` command that regenerates `$LS_COLORS` based on the configuration stored in `~/.dircolors` will be run again as well, overriding your modifications.

So here, what you need to do is:

1. find out where the `list-colors` zstyle is defined in your startup files
2. if it's based on `$LS_COLORS`, find out how that `$LS_COLORS` is being defined and fix it. And if not, adjust that call to `zstyle` to match your colour preferences.

Comment: Actually, it was a problem with my terminal (Knosole) theme and not a problem of ZSH. I'll edit my question stating this. However, thanks for explaining this into such detail and sorry for the trouble. At the very least, it'll be useful for someone in the future.